# Pass TupleTag to DoFn method

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to have two outputs from a DoFn method, following example of [Apache Beam programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs)

Basically in the example you pass a TupleTag and then specify to where make the output, this works for me the problem is that I call an external method inside the ParDo, and don't know how to pass this TupleTag, this is my code:

```
PCollectionTuple processedData = pubEv
  .apply("Processing", ParDo.of(new HandleEv())
      .withOutputTags(mainData, TupleTagList.of(failedData)));
```

HandleEv method:

```
static class HandleEv extends DoFn<String, String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
      c.output("test")
      c.output(failedData,"failed")
    }
}
```

The error I get is that `cannot find symbol` as failedData is not accesible from HandleEv, I tried to declare failedData at beginning of class but doesn't work neither.

Thank you very much

Comment: What is TupleTag ? This very basic but I want to in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this the same way you would pass a value to any other object --
 pass it in as an argument to the constructor of `HandleEv` and store it in a field:

```
static class HandleEv extends DoFn<String, String> {
  private final TupleTag<String> failedData;
  public HandleEv(TupleTag<String> failedData) {
    this.failedData = failedData;
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    c.output("test")
    c.output(failedData,"failed")
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
PCollectionTuple processedData = pubEv
  .apply("Processing", ParDo.of(new HandleEv(failedData))
      .withOutputTags(mainData, TupleTagList.of(failedData)));
```

Comment: Seems it works, I will complete the logic to handle the side output to verify if I can access what was saved to the TupleTag and will confirm the answer, thank you!